# mvc with ajax content make spider friendly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, googlebot

I have music site on mvc5 and there are pages with artist info and music tracks which loaded by ajax in table. For example this page http://freemusiclib.com/artist/Rihanna

The problem is google dont see content of ajax table http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ZtBOGAwtc84J:freemusiclib.com/artist/Rihanna+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

What the best practice for make it spider friendly for google and leave ajax based for users?

**Idea #1**
Because that table loads from server side I can make some switcher

a) if it is a spider bot - load table as part of page

b) if it is a real user - load the table with ajax with paging
Main problem here how found our based on request is it spider or not? There are a lot of spiders like google, bing and etc.

Do we have any C# logic which based on http request can say it is spider bot of not?

**Idea #2**
I have sitemaps with over 200 000 links to "artist" pages. I can add some special param to those links, but in that case google will show those links to users and when they click on it my site logic will think it is google bot.

So I need some advice here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Request.IsAjaxRequest` to determine if the request was made via AJAX. If it was, then it was a real user, otherwise it was a spider.

Comment: When you found in google link like http://freemusiclib.com/artist/Rihanna and click on it it will be usual usual http request. So it doesnt tell is it google bot or some user. I mean first link which you open on site can't be ajax request.